# AngularFIre: limit queries to users that has a specific value

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire to interact with my collections on firebase. I have a query which limit the number of queries, but with I also need, is to show only users which have a specific value. For example, I just want to show users which have profile pictures. How do I can do this in the query?

```
users: Observable<any[]>;

this.users = firestore.collection<User>('users', ref => ref.limit(10) ).valueChanges();
```

I looked for it on the documentation, but I can't find nothing that could help me

I think it could be something like:

```
this.users = firestore.collection<User>('users', ref => ref.limit(10) ).where("photoUrl", "==", true).valueChanges();
```

but it didn't work for me.

when I do that I got the error:

> Property 'where' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection'.

Comment: That second query looks fine to me at first glance. "it didn't work for me" is incredibly hard to help with. What isn't working about it? Can you possibly `console.log` somehting that shows the problem, and then edit the question to show that updated code and its output?

Comment: Hi, I just updated the question with the error I got. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to review the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) on how to add a filter to a query in AngularFire.  You want this instead:

```
this.users = firestore.collection<User>('users', ref =>
    ref.where("photoUrl", "==", true).limit(10)
).valueChanges();
```